# add an icon next to each row in the table using bootstrap vue?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue, bootstrap-table

I have a table that uses bootstrap Vue's table. Each row of the table corresponds to an item. My current problem is I need to add an icon next to each row, and display them every time I hover over that row, and then do some function when I click on this icon. But I can't find a way to add an icon. I have tried following the instructions on **https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table** with using slots but it only works for `#head` and `#cell`. Need an idea on this issue. This is my code and a picture describe my problem

```
<b-table
        ref="table"
        class="minh--30 mh--100 overflow-y-auto"
        bordered
        responsive
        :items="items"
        :fields="fields"
      >
        <template #head()="data">
          <span>{{ $t(data.field.label) }}</span>
        </template>

        <template #cell(field)="data">
          <span
            v-if="data.item.isDrag"
            class="d-block p-3"
          >{{ data.item.field }}</span>
          <b-dropdown
            v-else
            right
            no-caret
            variant="white"
            class="minw--40 w-100"
            menu-class="w-100 mh--24 overflow-auto minw-unset"
          >
            <template #button-content>
              <div
                class="flex-center minh--11 text-normal position-relative px-2"
              >
                <span class="pr-5 word-break text-line-clamp-1">{{ data.item.field }}</span>
                <i
                  class="fas fa-chevron-down position-absolute top-50 end--1 translate-middle-y px-2"
                />
              </div>
            </template>
            <b-dropdown-item
              v-for="item in listField"
              :key="item.id"
              variant="normal py-2"
              class="fs-12 fs-xl-15"
              @click="selectField(item, data)"
            >
              <span class="word-break text-line-clamp-1">{{ $t(item.text) }}</span>
            </b-dropdown-item>
          </b-dropdown>
        </template>

        <template #cell(action)="data">
          <b-dropdown
            right
            no-caret
            variant="white"
            class="minw--40 w-100"
            menu-class="w-100 mh--24 overflow-auto minw-unset"
          >
            <template #button-content>
              <div
                class="flex-center minh--11 text-normal position-relative px-2"
              >
                <span class="pr-5 word-break text-line-clamp-1">{{ data.item.action }}</span>
                <i
                  class="fas fa-chevron-down position-absolute top-50 end--1 translate-middle-y px-2"
                />
              </div>
            </template>
            <b-dropdown-item
              v-for="item in listDropdown"
              :key="item.id"
              variant="normal py-2"
              class="fs-12 fs-xl-15"
              @click="selectItem(item, data)"
            >
              <span class="word-break text-line-clamp-1">{{ $t(item.text) }}</span>
            </b-dropdown-item>
          </b-dropdown>
        </template>

        <template #cell(selectCharacter)="data">
          <b-dropdown
            right
            no-caret
            variant="white"
            class="minw--40 w-100"
            menu-class="w-100 mh--24 overflow-auto minw-unset"
          >
            <template #button-content>
              <div
                class="flex-center minh--11 text-normal position-relative px-2"
              >
                <span class="pr-5 word-break text-line-clamp-1">{{ data.item.selectCharacter }}</span>
                <i
                  class="fas fa-chevron-down position-absolute top-50 end--1 translate-middle-y px-2"
                />
              </div>
            </template>
            <b-dropdown-item
              v-for="item in listCharacter"
              :key="item.id"
              variant="normal py-2"
              class="fs-12 fs-xl-15"
              @click="selectCharacter(item, data)"
            >
              <span class="word-break text-line-clamp-1">{{ $t(item.text) }}</span>
            </b-dropdown-item>
          </b-dropdown>
        </template>

        <template #cell(inputCharacter)="data">
          <input
            v-model="data.item.inputCharacter"
            type="text"
            class="form-control h--11 border-0"
          >
        </template>

        <template #cell(startPosition)="data">
          <input
            v-model="data.item.startPosition"
            type="number"
            class="form-control h--11 border-0"
          >
        </template>

        <template #cell(characterCount)="data">
          <input
            v-model="data.item.characterCount"
            type="number"
            class="form-control h--11 border-0"
          >
        </template>

        <template #cell(needReplace)="data">
          <input
            v-model="data.item.needReplace"
            type="text"
            class="form-control h--11 border-0"
          >
        </template>

        <template #cell(replace)="data">
          <input
            v-model="data.item.replace"
            type="text"
            class="form-control h--11 border-0"
          >
        </template>

        <template #cell(delete)="data">
          <div class="flex-center pt-1">
            <input
              v-if="!data.item.isDrag"
              v-model="data.item.delete"
              type="checkbox"
            >
          </div>
        </template>
      </b-table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on reading the documentation, the table component wasn't designed for this use case because you are adding icons that are outside of the table itself.

One alternative would be to use the grid system https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/layout#layout-and-grid-system to create one narrow column on the left for the icons and one wide column on the right for the table. In the narrow column, you could create rows that are exactly the height of each row of the table so that the items stay aligned with each row.

Another alternative would be to use the `#cell` slot, and put an element inside that uses CSS, possibly the `transform` property (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp), to make the element appear to the left of where it really is.